# Unknown script/swf gets added under body

Tags: javascript, html

3 weeks ago i putted my website online now after 3 weeks a strange script under the body tag appears. Thing is, it is not inserted in the code so i can't remove it. I run a codeigniter website. The thing is all my permissions were on 777. I changed it but still the script and SWF object were added under the body tag.

swf and script that are added.

```
<div id="dp_swf_engine" style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px;">
</body>
<script src="http://i.spigotjs.info/opt_1398856699078/opt_content.js?partner=spig&channel=spigFF&appTitle=" type="application/x-javascript">
</html>
```

Comment: A google for `spigotjs` is returning a lit of antivirus related sites... I'll see if I can find anything of use

Comment: its most likely that you have a plugin in your browser that is putting that script there. Take a look on a different website, is the same script there too?? I think you have a virus. Try running IE with no add-ons, is most likely not going to be there then.

Comment: Meanwhile, run a scan with [MalwareBytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) and [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download). Also, [this site](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/507099/help-with-removing-spigot-virus-malware-or-adware/) seems to have a few solutions.

Comment: did you get it removed? i got the same script added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several places where such a script can be injected:

1. A cracker might have gained access to your server and modified the sources. Download the software onto a different computer and compare it with the latest version from your version control system. Don't use version control? Start right now.

   This code is often hard to find since it's encrypted. So you really need to check every single line of code.
2. A cracker might have installed a filter or front end on the server. That means the requests are intercepted by some other software, sent to your code for processing and then modified afterwards.

   I'm not aware of any Trojans which do this but in theory, they can install new system libraries or kernel modules which do this kind of filtering, so they are very hard to find. If that's the case, wipe the server and install everything from a clean source.
3. Do you get the same script for other sites, too? Then your local browser may be infected.

   Try to install another browser and update your anti-virus software.
4. If you use the Google webmaster tools, then Google will do a virus check of your site. If they find something, you'll get a warning on the dashboard.

**Important:** If your server was tainted, you need to tell your visitors about this. If you have their email addresses, send them an email telling them about the incident and how to clean their computers.

You should also put a big fat warning on the front page, so recurring visitors are warned.

Comment: I checked another site. And like you said the script is also inserted there. The script gets inserted only with the firefox browser. Chrome/Safari is ok.

Comment: Try to start Firefox without any plugins. If that doesn't help, reinstall Firefox.

Comment: I checked on a few other computers and the script is not inserted there. SO i guess it's pure a virus/malware on my computer. Also i use the program Vuze that might be the problem too.

Comment: Clean your computer and then reset all your passwords (since the virus might have stolen them as you typed them into your web browser).

Answer (score 0):

The extension "Awesome screenshot" installs this "dp_swf_engine.swf" thing ...

This is the file: http://www.ajaxcdn.org/swf.swf
and you can easily decode and view the code here:http://www.showmycode.com/ 
it seems to have lots of google analytics code?!

Not sure if it does any harm... 
anyone with some action script eye who can see whats going on here ?

J!